# What does hibernate validate for underlying db on spring application statup

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I am not using hibernate validator maven dependency in my springboot project and I really don't see any errors being thrown on application startup when my entity definition doesn't match with the underlying table.
wondering what does hibernate present in the classpath validate on application startup as it pertains to the underlying db

Answer (score 0):

I think it does nothing, until you define a property

```
    spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
```

In this case it will cross check your entities with the actual database model.